# Combining GEE layers to create a global categorical raster with class values?

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, image, feature-collection

[image: GEE Code and Map Example]

I've been making a climate map of the world and each climate zone is stored in a different variable (i.e. warmtemperatedry, cooltemperatemoist, cooltemperatedry as you can see in the picture).

I'd like to combine all the zones into one raster image with assigned numbers or text that correspond to the climate zones. Does anyone know how I'd do this in GEE?

I tried using the code below, but it doesn't add anything to the map and the feature collection when printed does not show the different climate zone names.

```
// Make a list of Features.
var list = [
  ee.Feature(tropicalmontane, {name: 'tropicalmontane'}),
  ee.Feature(tropicalwet, {name: 'tropicalwet'}),
  ee.Feature(tropicaldry, {name: 'tropicaldry'}),
  ee.Feature(warmtemperatemoist, {name: 'warmtemperatemoist'}),
  ee.Feature(warmtemperatedry, {name: 'warmtemperatedry'}),
  ee.Feature(cooltemperatemoist, {name: 'cooltemperatemoist'}),
  ee.Feature(cooltemperatedry, {name: 'cooltemperatedry'}),
  ee.Feature(borealmoist, {name: 'borealmoist'}),
  ee.Feature(borealdry, {name: 'borealdry'}),
  ee.Feature(polarmoist, {name: 'polarmoist'}),
  ee.Feature(polardry, {name: 'polardry'})
];

// Create a FeatureCollection from the list and print it.
var climatezones = ee.FeatureCollection(list);
print(climatezones, "climate zones");

Map.addLayer(climatezones, {palette: "#e97878, #0c6f4b, #3ca04, #eaec86, #209ed6, #df9625, #a8d477, #b178b3, #354a8b, #d4d49c, #c3e4d8, #edd9e9"}, "climate zones");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to convert my variables into a binary by using .gt(0) or .lt(0) and then multiplying the areas of presence (now assigned a value of 1) by the number I wanted to associate them with. For the below example of polar dry, I used 12.

From there, I created a list of images and converted them to floats.

After that, I created an image collection from the list of images, selected the band that I assigned to all of the variables, and mosaicked all of the images in the collection.

Lastly, I added the mosaicked image to my map for visualization!

```
// Polar Dry
var pd = lte0_temp.updateMask(lt10_months_temp).updateMask(mappet.lte(1)).rename("climatezone");
var polardry = pd.lt(0).multiply(12);
Map.addLayer(polardry, {palette: "#edd9e9"}, "polardry, pink", false);


// Make a list of Images and convert them to floats.
var list = [
  ee.Image(tropicalmontane).toFloat(),
  ee.Image(tropicalwet).toFloat(),
  ee.Image(tropicalmoist).toFloat(),
  ee.Image(tropicaldry).toFloat(),
  ee.Image(warmtemperatemoist).toFloat(),
  ee.Image(warmtemperatedry).toFloat(),
  ee.Image(cooltemperatemoist).toFloat(),
  ee.Image(cooltemperatedry).toFloat(),
  ee.Image(borealmoist).toFloat(),
  ee.Image(borealdry).toFloat(),
  ee.Image(polarmoist).toFloat(),
  ee.Image(polardry).toFloat()
];

// Create a Image Collection from the list
var climatezones = ee.ImageCollection(list).select('climatezone').mosaic();

// Visualize
Map.addLayer(climatezones, {min:1, max: 12, palette: "e97878, 0c6f4b, 3ca046, eaec86, 209ed6, df9625, a8d477, b178b3, 354a8b, d4d49c, c3e4d8, edd9e9"}, "climate zones");
```