# How to merge Map.addLayer on the Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, vector, merge, vector-layer, function

i'm working on vector data on the google earth engine. I want to make my script layer more simple. how to make my Map.addLayer script only 1 line script? I have tried to combine it with ".merge()" but it says ".merge is not a function". this is the link to access my script [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/2332957d1b21d8a983a8894392a6140b)

this is my script

```
//---------------------------------------------------------//
//---------------------------Data All----------------------//
//---------------------------------------------------------//

var area = ee.FeatureCollection(table)

var kosong = area.filter(ee.Filter.eq('GTAll', 0));
var rendah = area.filter(ee.Filter.gt('GTAll', 0)).filter(ee.Filter.lt('GTAll', 6));
var sedang = area.filter(ee.Filter.gt('GTAll', 6)).filter(ee.Filter.lt('GTAll', 15));
var tinggi = area.filter(ee.Filter.gt('GTAll', 15))

var data= function(hm){
  var kosongwarna= Map.addLayer(area,{color:'grey'},'Batas Administrasi');
  var kosongwarna= Map.addLayer(kosong,{},'Belum Ada KKN (0 Kasus)');
  var rendahwarna= Map.addLayer(rendah,{color:'red'},'Jumlah KKN Rendah (<6)');
  var sedangwarna= Map.addLayer(sedang,{color:'yellow'},'Jumlah KKN Sedang (6-15)');
  var tinggiwarna= Map.addLayer(tinggi,{color:'green'},'Jumlah KKN TInggi (>15)');
  var mergeinaja= hm.merge(kosongwarna).merge(rendahwarna).merge(sedangwarna).merge(tinggiwarna)
  return mergeinaja
}
Map.addLayer(area.map(data),'Layer')
Map.setCenter(120,0.5,5);
```

Comment: What is the intended output of this project? It's not clear to me. Why are you trying to merge `Map.addLayer`s? They're for drawing maps to creating collection or storing data, just display. Are you trying to merge the new layers that you create with the `filter`s into one collection?

Comment: I want to make my data look like a choropleth map. i'm not using "filter" for merge the new layers, but for classified the data.

Comment: I am far from an expert in GEE, so I could be completely off-base, but I don't think you'd make a choropleth in this manner. It might help your question if you edit it somehow to say that your intended outcome is a choropleth map. I THINK it's a matter of how you assign the `palette` in the `Map.addLayer` call that draws the map. Maybe it needs some kind of function in it? I really don't know.  https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/feature_collections_visualizing  https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/image_visualization#rendering-categorical-maps

Comment: Maybe this can help with your objective. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/430890/combining-gee-layers-to-create-a-global-categorical-raster-with-class-values